# gem install doesn't update .so files if changed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to create a **gem** which includes a C extension. I'm using the standard `Gem::PackageTask` to make the gem.

When I install the gem it builds the `.so` file properly and installs it in three locations:

```
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/nmatrix-atlas-0.1.0/nmatrix_atlas.so
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nmatrix-atlas-0.1.0/lib/nmatrix_atlas.so
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nmatrix-atlas-0.1.0/ext/nmatrix_atlas/nmatrix_atlas.so
```

I'm curious as to why it makes three copies of this. But anyway, the first one is the one that actually gets loaded when i do `require 'whatever'`. The problem is that when I make a change to the code, then repackage the gem, then run `gem install` again, the new code gets compiled into a new .so and the latter two .so's get replaced with the new, but the first one doesn't get updated. So ruby still sees the old code. I have to do `gem uninstall` followed by `gem install` to get it to update.

Is this a bug in rubygems? Or is it the expected behavior? Or am I doing something else wrong?

EDIT: For anyone who is curious, I filed a [bug on rubygems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1285). No response yet.

Comment: Not 100% sure if relevant, but... do you bump the gem's version?